# Insert extra row into UITableView like Tweetbot iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have `NSFetchedResultsController` like datasource of my `UITableView`. It displays some entities with predicate from my database. I try to find an elegant solution to insert utility row between my data rows. I don't want to create fake entity in my database cause I don't want to mix View and Model. But I need to have ability to recreate this utility row (e.g. on other application launch). Any suggestions?

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: when does this utility row appear ? when clicked on or ?

Comment: I have news flow, so utility row appear when it is gap in timeline. Same behavior as twitter timeline. I load 10 new news and have some old news, but it is some not loaded news in between

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet, in my opinion, is to use a section header or footer for that "utility" row.  In the case of Tweetbot, they're most likely caching results locally and then merge in data when the plus button is tapped.  Your table will take multiple data sets as arrays (an array of arrays) and treat each separate array as a chunk and put it into its own section.

Any way you implement you'll want to wrap your results from the database with some sort of metadata.  I think you're going to have to get away from a fetched results controller, unless you use a separate instance for each chunk, keeping track of the date range for each chunk.

Comment: Aaron Douglas, thank you for your answer. I can't use section header or footer, because they are float above the content and all solutions to prevent it a little bit hacking. I think that i have to create fake entity and use another custom utility cell for it. It would be the simplest, but not quite right solution.